# How to create MediaPlayer from string in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm currently trying to make an app that plays a sound, and worked using:

```
soundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio1);
soundPlayer.start();
```

`audio1.mp3` is in the `\res\raw` resource.
Now I'm trying to do the same but instead of using `R.raw`, I want to get the file from a string that contains the file name.

I tried this code that i found in another similar question in here but the id is ALWAYS zero:

```
public void playSound(String audioToPlay){
    int sound_id = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("audio1.mp3", "raw", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    if (sound_id != 0) {
        soundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, sound_id);
        soundPlayer.start(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```java
int sound_id = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("audio1.mp3", "raw", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

with:

```java
int sound_id = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("audio1", "raw", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

At runtime, resources do not have file extensions.